# Avalon Dock: How to set LayoutAnchorablePaneControl's BorderBrush

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I snooped the desired property and I can change it in real-time:

[image]

But I don't know what exactly to set in the code.
When I edit the XAML like this:

```
<dock:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" ...>
...
     <dock:DockingManager.AnchorablePaneControlStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneControl}">
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkRed"/>
         </Style>
     </dock:DockingManager.AnchorablePaneControlStyle>
...
```

I get the border color changed but the rest of behavior is unusable:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not get the big picture yet for what you wanna get, but I think you have to edit  the `Theme.xaml` file containing all `AvalonDock` Styles and have a look there at the following style:

```
    <Style x:Key="AvalonDock_AnchorablePaneControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutAnchorablePaneControl}">
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Model.Root.Manager.Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AvalonDock_BaseColor8}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">...
```

Then you can see that the `Background` property is binded to a `DynamicResource`. You have to change the value of `AvalonDock_BaseColor8` resource accordingly to what you want to achieve.